# Where did ~/.gvfs go on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, mount, samba, gvfs

Where did `~/.gvfs` go on Ubuntu 12.10. How can I find the location of the mounted through samba folders?

I share a folder with a Ubuntu 12.10 machine. I am trying to find the location of the mount point on another Ubuntu 12.10 machine that I've mounted it. It is mounted successfully. It is on the nautilus sidebar. But I can not find the location as on 12.04 which was `~/.gvfs/blabla` to use the folder in an app.

Answer (score 24):

It's changed to `/run/user/$USER/gvfs`, where $USER is your_username.

It may also be at: `/run/user/$(id -u)/gvfs`, where `id -u` is the effective user ID.

Example: `/run/user/1000/gvfs`.