# What is the ~/.gvfs file?

Tags: 14.04

I recently made a fresh install of **Ubuntu 14.04** and I noticed an item **.gvfs** in my **home folder**.

It is very strange, since it is visible even though it has a leading `.`

[image]

What is even stranger is that I cannot determine the owner of the file:

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 martin martin 4096 juil.  6 17:48 .gstreamer-0.10
d?????????  ? ?      ?         ?              ? .gvfs
-rw-rw-r--  1 martin martin   68 nov.  16  2013 .hgrc
```

**EDIT:**

I am sorry, I put my question too vaguely:

1. What is the purpose of this file/directory?
2. Why doesn't it contain any information in `ls -la`?
3. What does its presence and corruption tell about my system?
4. What should I do with it?
5. Why is it visible even with a preceding `.`?

**EDIT2:**

After reboot, the item disappeared.

Comment: In 12.04 it's an empty folder.

Comment: It is not a file, but a directory which should be a FUSE mount handled by the gvfs-fuse-daemon process and in your case it seems to be [corrupted](https://www.google.com/search?q=~/.gvfs+corrupted).

Answer (score 4):

It serves as mount point for GVFS-Fuse.

> gvfs is a userspace virtual filesystem where mount runs as a separate
>   processes which you talk to via dbus. It also contains a gio module
>   that seamlessly adds gvfs support to all applications using the gio
>   API. It also supports exposing the gvfs mounts to non-gio applications
>   using fuse.<sup>[Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/libs/gvfs-fuse)</sup>

Comment: ~/.gvfs has been moved to , see http://askubuntu.com/questions/211414/where-did-gvfs-go-on-ubuntu-12-10 There is some discussion here as well http://askubuntu.com/questions/61196/why-do-my-gvfs-mounts-not-show-up-under-gvfs-or-run-user-login-gvfs . Not sure what the OP problems is, however.

Answer (score 0):

This is a FUSE mount point. By default, FUSE will prevent other users (even root) from accessing your FUSE mounts. I believe that this directory was mounted under a different user, or you are viewing the directory through a different user.

[See this question for an explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17402/why-does-root-get-permission-denied-when-accessing-fuse-directory)