# How can access another folder on another machine using file manager

Tags: 12.04

How can I access another folder on another machine? In Windows explorer, I can enter

```
\\10.152.34.13\projects\myfiles
```

and I see all the folders under that directory. But how can I the same under ubuntu file manager?

Comment: write >> `smb:\\10.152.34.13\projects\myfiles `  in any browser then goto explorer it will automatically mount this sharable folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the file explorer Nautilus by opening your home folder.
2. Click "File", "Connect to server".
3. In the "Server" field, enter the IP address of the computer you want to access. In the "Type" field, choose "Windows share". Click "Connect".

[image: Connect to Server dialog]

The folder should open, and it will be listed in the sidebar under "Network":

[image: File explorer with Network section highlighted]

Alternatively, you can also use the "Browse Network" entry as bitsnbites suggested.

Comment: And a related question, how can I copy files from \\10.152.34.13\projects\myfiles at command line? I do *NOT* have an account at that server, so I can't use scp, right?

Comment: `scp` is for copying files over an SSH connection. Windows Shares do not use SSH, so it's not the right command to use. For the answer to your question, have a look at: http://askubuntu.com/questions/29535/how-do-i-access-a-mounted-windows-share-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

After opening file manager, selecting Browse Network in the lower left should allow you to see network devices, after which you can navigate to the folders you wish to view. It might also help to mount the external location, but I haven't tried this http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/22518/how-to-mount-a-remote-folder-in-ubuntu/