# How do I access a mounted Windows server from the command line

Tags: networking, command-line, server, mount, samba

I don't know much about networking so please help me.
I am using Ubuntu **16.04** and I connect to windows server of my university by going to Places `> Connect to Server` and there I enter `smb://fileserver2` followed by my user-name and password and I easily access whatever I want to access from nautilus but I want to access this server from command terminal(like other mounted drives by going to /media) so how can I do that?

P.S.- I have already seen [How do I access a mounted Windows share from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29535/how-do-i-access-a-mounted-windows-share-from-the-command-line) and this does not help.

Comment: What didn't work?

Comment: @Anwar when I use command `mount -t smbfs //servername/myshare /mnt/servername/myshare -o username=myself` with my servername and username it gives error `stating mount: mount point /mnt/fileserver2/14102126 does not exist` where 14102126 is my shared folder

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you using ?

Comment: @Danturnip 16.04 (also mentioned in question).