# Ubuntu 17.10 on a windows domain

Tags: networking, windows, 17.10

I'm currently setting up a Ubuntu 17.10 machine (fresh install) and I can't seem to get it on the domain. I'm pretty new to Ubuntu so please be detailed! I've tried to look elsewhere for the answer, but it seems like all the answers I got were either out of date, or the commands didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `get it on the domain`?

Comment: Hi derHugo,  We want to access a Domain, (for user logins and to share resources.) From a windows perspective I'm not sure how to word it otherwise!

Comment: What did you try so far? Have a look into `samba`. Do you want to share things on your Ubuntu machine or just access a share on your Domain?

Comment: We tried using samba, but we're not sure how anything works! If you have any screenshots or resources that'd be great! We have a server that windows users can access for user login information, we'd like to be able to access the domain just like we would on windows.

Comment: For creating a samba server so you can share stuff on the Ubuntu Machine: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-samba-server-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: What have you tried? Have you for instance had a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryWinbindHowto ?

Comment: For accessing an existent share from terminal: https://askubuntu.com/a/29598/423684

Comment: When we type "sudo apt install samba" this is the error that happens


Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package samba is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  samba-libs

E: Package 'samba' has no installation candidate

Comment: For accessing an existent share from the GUI: enter `//HOST​` in the filebrowser. Or if you need a specific path `//HOST/PATH`

Comment: Derhugo, //HOST shows no results?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Samba. If you have the Synaptic Package Manager look for Samba. This should do the trick. SAMBA.ORG has lots of information available.